# Max-Cut approximation algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

The semidefinite programming algorithm by Goemans and Williamson (GW) guarantees a 0.878-approximation of MaxCut. If the UGC is true, this is the best approximation one can achieve unless NP=P.

For a graph G=(V,E) there exist 2^|V| possible cuts. Are there any results on how large the set of cuts is which are better the GW-approximation, i.e. 
$N(cuts_\mathrm{better})/2^{|V|}$. As MaxCut is NP, I would assume that this ratio should not be constant, but exponentially decreasing with the number of vertices. Is that intuition right and are there any results on that?

Comment: Assuming that $G$ has no isolated vertices, my instinct would be that almost all (all except an exponentially small fraction of) cuts cut only $|E|(\frac{1}{2}+o(1))$ edges.  I don't recall seeing a proof of this anywhere though [If you replace "exponentially small" by "$o(1)$" this would follow from Chebyshev's inequality, since different edges being cut are pairwise independent].  This would suggest any counterexample would have to be one where the maxcut is only $\approx$half the edges.

Comment: If this doesn't get an answer in the next few days you might also want to try posting this question at the CSTheory Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks a lot for your answer - and sorry for my late reply! Seeing that your instinct tells you a similar thing already helps, I don't have a good intuition for this. I think I'll post it to CSTheory as well. If I do, I'll comment the link here.